# Show/Hide Layout onTouch in framelayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a full image fragment. There is a RelativeLayout and LinearLayout in framelayout. LinearLayout contain viewpager.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutViewpager">


    <com.bogdwellers.pinchtozoom.view.ImageViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayoutforbuttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want When user first open it it should only show image(Viewpager layout) and if user click on it that show other option like - share and save(RelativeLayout).
We can find this type of feature in facebook and whatsapp.

Comment: Use Native share intent instead of your own layout

Comment: Try my updated answer, it is working and tested.

Comment: Why did you remove acceptance from my answer.you said @Android Team's answer is not working as you expect.You should accept the answer which worked for you and if it is helpful you should upvote..

Comment: by mistake, Sorry .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply hide or unhide the relativeLayout's instance using **setVisibility.(..)** method on linearLayout or imageviewpager click.

layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutViewpager">


        <ImageViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:onClick="onPagerClick"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onSave"
        android:text="Save" />


</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Activity:

```
   public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isButtonShown = false;
    ImageViewPager viewPager;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        layout = findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);




    }


    public void onPagerClick(View view) {

        if (isButtonShown) {
            isButtonShown = false;
            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            isButtonShown = true;
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this type code for visiablity ..

```
private void share(){
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    linearLayoutViewpager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


 linearLayoutViewpager=findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutViewpager);
    linearLayoutViewpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    relativeLayout=findViewById(R.id.relativelayoutforbuttons);
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

it only sample code but mange according your needs.

```
     final boolean flag=true;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (flag){
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flag=false;
            }
            else{
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: There should be a toggle method. If user click again relative should be visible.

Comment: that time take one boolean value then first user click it true on that time relative layout visiable other then it set as false then user click on next time then not visiable .. it means take if else condition based on boolean value.

Comment: i update my answer and add some logical codition in visiablity but it mange accroding  your needs.

Comment: cannot assign value to final variable flag.

Comment: remove final type.

Comment: make that variable class level

Comment: final variable accessed wihin inner class, needs to be declare final.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: and there is no button. onlt "relativelayout.setOnclicklistner"

Comment: boolean flag=true; define as class level

Comment: as i told you there is no any button. show which layout i choose for onclick.

Comment: used that layout that perform hide or show for click event.

Comment: thats the problem. I tried every layout but only RelativeLayout work and after it's GONE, it dont come back.

Comment: then perform hide ans show code into relative layout click event.

Comment: relativelayoutObject.setOnClickListener.

Comment: there's a problem. Created a button. it works first 2 time, Visible and gone. but after this it dont work.

Comment: [Show-hide toggle button for Layout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136540/show-hide-toggle-button-for-layout-in-android) this worked.

Comment: Did you try my answer, It is working as you expect.just check it.